# How to get rid of String Quotes in a Grid with NotebookWrite to Text Cell

Tags: notebooks

I'm trying to write a Grid with strings to a notebook.
The Cell I'm creating should be a Text Cell.
When the NotebookWrite is executed I get the String displayed with quotes.
Is there a way to get rid of these?

```
nb = CreateDocument[]
NotebookWrite[nb,Cell[ToBoxes@Text[Style[Grid[{{"one", "two"}}, Frame -> All],Black, 14]],"Text"]]
```

Comment: add `ShowStringCharacters -> False`.

Comment: What! That is not documented in the Cell documentation. How did you know this so fast! I find it very hard to manipulate Notebooks and the documentation is very high level. One step further and I end in a swamp.. Thx!

Comment: Because I already knew that, but I agree it is not easy to find if you don't. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionsForExpressionInputAndOutput.html